# Are regular tea bags effective in treating pink eye?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine

http://myculturedpalate.com/blog/2013/03/11/tea-bags-a-natural-remedy-for-pink-eye/

or http://altmedicine.about.com/od/healthconditionsdisease/a/pinkeye.htm

> Chamomile is also used in folk medicine to treat pink eye. Brewing a cup of chamomile tea, removing the tea bag and allowing it to cool, and placing the bag over your infected eye may help alleviate irritation.

or http://www.streetdirectory.com/food_editorials/beverages/coffee/salt_teabags_and_coffee_home_remedies_for_pink_eye.html

> Quite a number of pink eye patients claim that tea bags work especially well for most sore eyes cases, specifically the black tea bags. This solution may also be combined with some amount of honey.

Comment: It's not clear whether the claim is that  it helps to cure the infection or simply relieves the symptoms. It's certainly plausible that something cool and moist would be soothing, so it might also be interesting to ask whether a teabag is  superior to, say, a cloth dampened with plain water.